# Can an ECS container have access to the docker socket?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have a docker image, the sole point of which is to launch sub docker images for continuous integration.

If I were to run it on any docker enabled computer, it would be:

```
docker run -d \
   -e DRONE_SERVER=wss://ci.fommil.com/ws/broker \
   -e DRONE_SECRET=... \
   -e DOCKER_MAX_PROCS=1 \
   -e DRONE_TIMEOUT=30m \
   -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock \
   --restart=always \
   --name=drone-agent \
   drone/drone:0.5 agent
```

But the ECS panel doesn't seem to allow me to pass the v flag. I don't think this is being passed, even if I select privileged mode.

This image only contains one binary. It is not possible to ssh in and poke around. How can I debug this using ECS tooling? e.g. to see the docker launch parameters.

And how can I get the socket mounted? Am I going to have to fall back to managing my own EC2 instance that launches docker?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I got this working!

The trick is to add a Volume at the Task level (left hand side of `-v`) and then in the Container level add this as a mount, choosing where to put it (right hand side of `-v`).

Comment: Hi, does your solution work today? I am trying to achieve the same, but AWS Interface has changed a little bit and I do not know how to reproduce it.

Comment: a little valentine's surprise from past fommil. How lovely!

Comment: It is incredible how complicated AWS has to make even the simplest things. Splitting up a `docker run` parameter into multiple fields over multiple levels is mind-boggingly overcomplicating. Naturally, it's not documented in an understandable way, either...

Comment: @fommil I know you got this working, but I'm still struggling with this any chance you could hand hold a little: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69945055/docker-v-flag-translated-to-aws-ecs-task-definition

Comment: bind mount doesn't allow for paths, and EFS expects well.. and EFS

Answer (score 7):

fommil posted already the solution.
It might be necessary to change the access rights to docker.sock in the running container as well.
Reason: After mounting the docker.socks the owner is set to root and as long as your actual user is not root he can't access it - which should be true.

**Don't** just try from within your docker container to chown $USER_NAME. /var/run/docker.sock

This will also change the permissions of the source and you won't be able to access it from the ec2-user account!

You need your user to be a member of the correct group OR this quick workaround:
Set the ownership to the user within the docker container but the group to the docker group of the outer ec2 instance.

Step by step:

Get the group id of your ec2-user:

```
id -G ec2-user
```

The output may look like:

```
[ec2-user@ip-10-0-xx-xxx ~]$ id -G ec2-user
500 10 **497**
```

In this case 497 is the id for the docker group that exists only in the outer docker shell (ECS-Instance). /var/run/docker.sock has to be assigned to the docker group so that you can access it.

The ids of users within docker containers are usually 0 for root and 1000 for the standard user.
To make sure that you don't guess: Simply log into the running docker container with docker exec (don't use -u 0) and check for the name at the beginning of your prompt the group id - same command as used above! This time you should note the **first** number. In this example (as it should be): 1000

Also check the actual settings for the docker.sock within the running docker container: ls -la /var/run/docker.sock

This should show owner settings *root 497*

The number (group) should match one of the numbers you have seen before. Now you know what to do:

1. Leave the docker container (as you have no root access to change the ownership).
2. `sudo chown 1000:497 /var/run/docker.socks`

That means that you assign as root the owner with the id 1000 and the group with the id 497 to /var/run/docker.socks

Even if the given id does not exist on the system this command works: The user id 1000 will most likely only exist within the inner docker container while the group 497 will only exist in the outer container.

That's it.

Comment: Great answer! Instead of modifying the ownership of `/var/run/docker.sock` in the EC2 instance, you can simply add the non-root user (inside the container) to the 'docker' group. Add the 'docker' group inside your image build, and then add your non-root user to the group. This is more idempotent and doesn't require changes to host machines.

I'm setting up vector.dev, and needed ECS log shipping. Here is what fixed the problem in my Dockerfile:

`RUN groupadd --gid 994 docker && usermod -a -G 994 vector`

Answer (score 0):

Adding to existing answers, here is a way to do it using the task definition json.

```
{
"family": "migrate-images",
"taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/ecsTaskRole",
"networkMode": "bridge",
"containerDefinitions": [
    {
        "name": "migrate-images",
        "image": "123456789012.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/my-docker-in-docker-image:latest",
        "cpu": 256,
        "memory": 512,
        "essential": true,
        "mountPoints": [
            {
                "sourceVolume": "docker_socket",
                "containerPath": "/var/run/docker.sock"
            }
        ]
    }
],
"volumes": [
    {
        "name": "docker_socket",
        "host": {
            "sourcePath": "/var/run/docker.sock"
        }
    }
]
}
```