# Docker -v flag translated to AWS ECS Task Definition

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, datadog, ecs-taskdefinition

I'm following the datadog guide here: https://docs.datadoghq.com/database_monitoring/setup_postgres/aurora/?tab=docker

which says to run this docker command:

```
docker run -e "DD_API_KEY=${DD_API_KEY}" \
  -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro \
  -l com.datadoghq.ad.check_names='["postgres"]' \
  -l com.datadoghq.ad.init_configs='[{}]' \
  -l com.datadoghq.ad.instances='[{
    "dbm": true,
    "host": "<AWS_INSTANCE_ENDPOINT>",
    "port": 5432,
    "username": "datadog",
    "password": "<UNIQUEPASSWORD>"
  }]' \
  gcr.io/datadoghq/agent:${DD_AGENT_VERSION}
```

That's all well and good, the labels are easy to configure; what's not clear to me is how to set the task definition for the volume (ideally in the console)

I'm not sure how to translate `-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro` into these inputs:
[image: ECS Task]
[image: ECS Container]

I currently have this in my `Dockerfile` (but I think that's only part of the solution - and potentially incorrect):

`VOLUME ["/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"]`

Answer (score 0):

That mapping is knowing as mounting the docker socket. Which means you are giving your container access to the docker daemon. Which in turns means it's a big deal. It works and some specific scenarios require that (e.g. a Jenkins container may need that to be able to launch new worker containers on the host). I don't know enough datadog to say what they use this for.

You don't map it inside of the `Dockerfile` but you are on the right path in terms of where you'd want to map it on the ECS console (see [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/amazon-ecs-plugin/issues/137)).

Please note that this setup would not be supported using Fargate (only EC2).